# How can you have a Tab Bar Controller and a Table View?

Tags: iphone, sdk, interface-builder

I am trying to make it so that on one of the tabs there is a table view

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This is a standard idiom (ie: recent calls in the phone app). You're gonna have to be more specific as to what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Use Interface builder to create a Tab Bar Controller and on one of the tabs add a Table View Controller. This is pretty basic and just requires dragging and dropping in Interface Builder and then connecting the outlets in Xcode.

There are plenty of tutorials online for this.